# How to disable Postgresql tools message translations

Tags: windows, postgresql

Postgresql tools (located in c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin) automatically localize all messages to language which is set in "Windows settings -> Clock, Language, and Region -> Change location -> Formats -> Format"

I would like to have Format set to my current language (not English) but I would like to force postgresql tools to use English for simple parsing of their responses.

How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Postgres tools pick their language from an environment variable named `LC_MESSAGES`. So if you define

```
LC_MESSAGES=English
```

Postgres error messages will be displayed in English

---

You can also change this on the Postgres side, by changing `lc_messages` in `postgresql.conf`:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-LC-MESSAGES

This will also make the messages in the Postgres logfile appear in English

Comment: I had defined LC_MESSAGES=English in postgresql.conf and this was not enough. Defining LC_MESSAGES=English in Windows environment variable seems to solve my problem. Thanks